# Why is valgrind giving me the wrong line location for my memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

```
#include "card.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int comparator(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    card_t *carda = *(card_t **)a; 
    card_t *cardb = *(card_t **)b; 
    return strcmp(carda->name, cardb->name);
    
    free(carda);
    free(cardb);

} 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    

    int num_entries = 0;
    card_t **cards = NULL;
    int freeCards = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t bufsiz = 0;
    int same = 0;

    //char *tempChar;
    int x = 0;
    
    FILE *input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    ssize_t result;
    getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
    while ( (result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file)) > 0){
        num_entries++;
        cards = realloc(cards, sizeof(card_t *) * num_entries);
        cards[x] = malloc(sizeof(card_t));

        char *stringp = buf;
        char *textCopy = strdup(buf);
        int tempInt  = atoi(strsep(&stringp, ","));
        same = 0;
        freeCards = 0;
        while (freeCards < num_entries){
            if (cards[freeCards]->id == tempInt){
                same = 1;
                free(cards[x]);
                free(textCopy);
                num_entries--;
            }
            freeCards++;
        }
        stringp++;
        char *sameName = strdup(strsep(&stringp, "\""));
        while (freeCards < num_entries){
            if (strcmp (cards[freeCards]->name, sameName)== 0){
                if (cards[freeCards]->id > tempInt){
                    same = 1;
                    free(cards[x]);
                    free(textCopy);
                    num_entries--;  
                }
                else{
                    cards[freeCards]->id = tempInt;
                    same = 1;
                    free(cards[x]);
                    free(textCopy);
                    num_entries--;  
                }
            }
            freeCards++;
        }
            
        
        if (same == 0){
            cards[x]->id = tempInt;
            //get name
            
            cards[x]->name =  sameName;
    
            //get cost
            stringp += 2;
            cards[x]->cost =  strdup(strsep(&stringp, "\""));
            
            //converted_cost
            stringp++;
            cards[x]->converted_cost = atoi(strsep(&stringp, "\""));
            
            //type 
            cards[x]->type =  strdup(strsep(&stringp, "\""));
            
            //text
            stringp+=2;
            cards[x]->text =  strdup(strsep(&stringp, "\""));
            //textLenght =strlen(stringp);
            //strsep(&stringp, "\"");
            
            //stats
            //afterTextLenght =strlen(stringp);
            stringp+= 2;
            cards[x]->stats =  strdup(strsep(&stringp, "\""));

            //rarity
            stringp+= 2;
            char *testRare = strsep(&stringp, "\"");
            if (strcmp ("common", testRare)== 0){
                cards[x]->rarity = 0;
            }else if (strcmp ("uncommon",testRare) == 0){
                cards[x]->rarity = 1;
            }else if (strcmp ("re",testRare) == 0){
                cards[x]->rarity = 2;
            }else{
                cards[x]->rarity = 3;
            }
            //printf("%ld====\n",result);
    
            
            //strncpy(textCopy, textCopy +(startLength-textLenght), (textLenght-afterTextLenght));
            //cards[x]->text =  strdup(textCopy);

            free(textCopy);
            x++;
            
        }
    }
        
        //qsort( cards, num_entries, sizeof(card_t *), comparator);

        
        freeCards = 0;
    while (freeCards < num_entries){
            printf("%-43s%s\n----------------------------------------------------\n",cards[freeCards]->name,cards[freeCards]->cost);
            if (cards[freeCards]->rarity == 0){
                printf("%-45s common\n----------------------------------------------------\n",cards[freeCards]->type);
            }else if(cards[freeCards]->rarity == 1){
                printf("%-43s uncommon\n----------------------------------------------------\n",cards[freeCards]->type);
            }else if (cards[freeCards]->rarity == 2){
                printf("%-47s rare\n----------------------------------------------------\n",cards[freeCards]->type);
            }else{
                printf("%-45s mythic\n----------------------------------------------------\n",cards[freeCards]->type);
            }
            printf("%s\n",cards[freeCards]->text);
            printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%52s\n",cards[freeCards]->stats);
            freeCards++;
    }


    freeCards = 0;
    while (freeCards < num_entries){
        free(cards[freeCards]->name);
        free(cards[freeCards]->cost);
        free(cards[freeCards]->type);
        free(cards[freeCards]->text);
        free(cards[freeCards]->stats);
        free(cards[freeCards]);
        freeCards++;
    }
    free(cards);
    free(buf);
    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;
    
}
```

```
enum rarity
{
    common,
    uncommon,
    rare,
    mythic
};

typedef struct card
{
    unsigned int id;
    char* name;
    char* cost;
    unsigned int converted_cost;
    char* type;
    char* text;
    char* stats;
    enum rarity rarity;
} card_t;
```

```
 make && valgrind -q --leak-check=yes ./parser short-cards-1.csv
make: 'parser' is up to date.
==24945== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24945==    at 0x108B2B: main (in /home/brandon/cs3240_system_programming_concepts_spring_2021/a1_mtg_card_data_parsing/parser)
==24945== 
Stolen by the Fae                          {X}{U}{U}
----------------------------------------------------
Sorcery                                         rare
----------------------------------------------------
Return target creature with converted mana cost X to its owner's hand. You create X 1/1 blue Faerie creature tokens with flying.
----------------------------------------------------
                                                    
Eternal Isolation                          {1}{W}
----------------------------------------------------
Sorcery                                       common
----------------------------------------------------
Put target creature with power 4 or greater on the bottom of its owner's library.
----------------------------------------------------
                                                    
Corpse Knight                              {W}{B}
----------------------------------------------------
Creature - Zombie Knight                    uncommon
----------------------------------------------------
Whenever another creature enters the battlefield under your control, each opponent loses 1 life.
----------------------------------------------------
                                                 2/2
Orzhov Enforcer                            {1}{B}
----------------------------------------------------
Creature - Human Rogue                      uncommon
----------------------------------------------------
Deathtouch\nAfterlife 1 (When this creature dies, create a 1/1 white and black Spirit creature token with flying.)
----------------------------------------------------
                                                 1/2
==24945== 18 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==24945==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24945==    by 0x4ED99B9: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==24945==    by 0x108B95: main (in /home/brandon/cs3240_system_programming_concepts_spring_2021/a1_mtg_card_data_parsing/parser)
```

So I'm not sure why valgrind is telling me my leak is at line 42 (`strdup.c:42`). I've tried going through my code myself and cant find where the leak is. so I was hoping valgrind would help but last I checked I don't need to free a statement that looks like `freeCards = 0`.

To clear thing up the point of the code is to take a CSV file and split it into a struct and sort it. I have everything working but can't find this memory leak.

Comment: `strdup.c` is the file implementing `strdup`. And line 42 is the line in that file.

Comment: by line 42 of the file are you talking about line 42 of main?. and I believe I'm freeing everything i strdup

Comment: Compile your code with debugging symbols (`-g` if using `gcc`). That will give you the line number for `main` and help point to the particular `strdup` that you are not freeing memory for.

Comment: It seems `sameName` is not freed in the case `same == 1`.

Comment: in the comparator function, this code: `return strcmp(carda->name, cardb->name);
    
    free(carda);
    free(cardb);`  will never execute the calls to `free()` because the function will already have exited due to the `return` statement.

Comment: does this `getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
    while ( (result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file)) > 0){` mean there is a column header line that you are skipping?

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly oompile!  when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted code results in (about) 10 warnings that need to be corrected.

Answer (score 3):

What Valgrind is telling you is that your `main` function is calling `strdup()` and that you are not freeing the pointer returned by `strdup()` afterwards. It then goes into more detail telling you that ***inside strdup*** the memory was allocated using `malloc()`, and points you to the line of *the C library source code* (not your code) which defines `strdup()` and does the actual call to `malloc()`. This is because you have the debugging symbols installed for the C library you're using (most likely `glibc`).

You do not care about any of this. You want to know where in your `main` is the offending `strdup()` call that causes a leak. In order to make Valgrind able to show you line number information for *your own program*, you must compile it with debugging information, which can be done for GCC/Clang using the `-g` compilation flag (e.g. `gcc -g prog.c -o prog`). After doing this and running Valgrind again, you will be able to see Valgrind point out which line of `main` is responsible for that call to `strdup()`.